# filter nested array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, keyword

having an array with objects and inside an options array how do I filter the inner array of objects by key value?

Here is the following example:

```
let test = [{
  "options": [{
     "label": "Audi",
     "value": 10
   },
    {
     "label": "BMW",
     "value": 18
   },
   {
     "label": "Mercedes Benz",
     "value": 116
   },
   {
     "label": "VW",
     "value": 184
   }
 ],
 "label": "test1"
},
{
 "options": [{
    "label": "Adler",
    "value": 3664
  },
  {
    "label": "Alfa Romeo",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "label": "Alpine",
    "value": 4
  }
],
 "label": "test2"
}
]
```

how do I get back the object:

```
 {
   "label": "Audi",
   "value": 10
 }
```

if I filter with keyword `Audi`

```
return label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase());
```

I tried with the following

```
test.map((k) => {
              res = k.options.filter((j) => {
                inputValue.toLowerCase();
                if (j.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())) {
                  return j;
                }
              });
            });
```

Comment: `filter()` is for creating a new array with elements that meet a condition. If you want to return an element that meets a condition, use `find()`.

Comment: You're not returning `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result of `filter()`, not just assign it to a variable, so that `map()` will return the results.

```js
let test = [{
    "options": [{
        "label": "Audi",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "label": "BMW",
        "value": 18
      },
      {
        "label": "Mercedes Benz",
        "value": 116
      },
      {
        "label": "VW",
        "value": 184
      }
    ],
    "label": "test1"
  },
  {
    "options": [{
        "label": "Adler",
        "value": 3664
      },
      {
        "label": "Alfa Romeo",
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "label": "Alpine",
        "value": 4
      }
    ],
    "label": "test2"
  }
]
let inputValue = "audi";
let search = inputValue.toLowerCase();
let result = test.map(k => k.options.filter(j => j.label.toLowerCase().includes(search)));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works I just had to concat the result for my use case!

Answer (score 1):

This will return all options matching the search query :

```js
function find(array, query) {
  return array.reduce((prev, current) => prev.concat(current.options), []).filter(item => item.label.includes(query))
}

find(test, 'Audi')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go two levels deep when traversing your array.

```js
function filterArray(needle, haystack) {
  return haystack
    .map(h => h.options)
    .flatMap(h => h )
    .filter(h => h.label.toLowerCase().includes(needle.toLowerCase()));
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-galois-mys5c?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thanks for showing me `flatMap()`, didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap()` followed by `filter()`:

```js
let test=[{options:[{label:"Audi",value:10},{label:"BMW",value:18},{label:"Mercedes Benz",value:116},{label:"VW",value:184}],label:"test1"},{options:[{label:"Adler",value:3664},{label:"Alfa Romeo",value:3},{label:"Alpine",value:4}],label:"test2"}]

let result = test.flatMap(el => {
    return el.options.filter(car => car.label == "Audi")
})[0]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might gile your answer:

console.log(test[0].options[0]);